# Open source task tracker/todo list with graph view

Tags: graphs, issue-tracker, plug-in, todo, task-management

**TLDR**:
Trying to find something like this.
[image: Easy WBS]

Long version:
I'm looking for task manager/todo list/issue tracker with ability to represent parent/child tasks by making a graph.
Some features I would like:

- Interactive, so I can move tasks, fold and unfold parents, create new links.
- Self-hosted, I want it for personal usage and don't want to store it on third-party servers.
- Traditional list view of tasks.
- Good UI, optional but would be great.
- Web-based, so I can access it with different devices.
- Free or at least not costing 300$+

Some programs that I already know but decided not use them:

- Jira with plugins [[1]](https://spartez.com/products/whiteboards-for-jira) [[2]](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/apps/1216207/issue-links-viewer). Not self-hosted + too expensive.
- [Trac](https://trac-hacks.org/wiki/TracTicketDepgraphPlugin). Bad UI + non-interactive graph.
- [Gameplan](https://gameplan.global). It's looks very cool but it's not self-hosted + I'm not sure if it has list view + too expensive.
- Redmine with [easy WBS](https://www.easyredmine.com/redmine-wbs-plugin) plugin (on the image above). It is the best solution I could find for now but live editing is under paywall + I don't really like redmine.

Comment: Hi, I want to point out that usually apps are not both web-based and self-hosted: programs with web-based interface often save data on cloud and if you need to access those data from multiple devices cloud data storage is mandatory.

Comment: @d3vmak Sorry for misleading about this. I had in mind some server-based service which I can deploy on my server and access it via browser.